# Increase of ClientAbortException after switching to http/2

Tags: spring-boot, http2

Since we switched to http/2 we see a lot of `ClientAbortException`. Either *Broken Pipe* or *Connection reset by peer*.

The setup is Client <-> HAProxy <-> Spring Boot 2 application with embedded Tomcat 8

Is this normal behavior? If not, what would be the best way to find out why the connection is broken?

Comment: We are seeing the exact same thing after turning on http/2 with Apache as proxy.